# Inject something into model with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to inject something into a model, when the model gets loaded with entity framework.

Consider the following user-model. I want the entity framework to inject SomeReference into each User getting loaded from the Database when doing context.Users.Where(somequery) gets executed.

```
public class User {

    public string Username {get; set;}

    public User(SomeReference ref)
    {
    }

}
```

Where can I register that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to add something like this in your `DbContext` constructor

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += 
(sender, args) =>
    {
    var user = args.Entity as User;
    if (user != null)
        user.SomeReference = ref;
    };
```

I guess next step would then be to rely on some kind of factory to retrieve various values for variable `ref`

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework can only use the parameterless constructor when fetching items from DB, so I'm afraid this is not possible, at least not directly. What I would do is make the default constructor private, and create a new constructor which takes a `User` and a `SomeReference`:

```
public class User 
{
   private User() {}
   public User(User user, SomeReference ref)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Then after the data is fetched from the database, you can use this constructor in a `Select`:

```
var result = db.Users.AsEnumerable().Select(u => new User(u, myRef)).ToList();
```

Note the `AsEnumerable()` call because you would get an error about the constructor because it can't be translated to SQL. Please **do** keep in mind that making the default constructor private [disables proxy creation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057.aspx) so you won't be able to make use of lazy loading/auto change tracking anymore. If you need it, you'll have to make the constructor public.